# O Conservador da Conservatória? Ou A Conservadora?

Tags: gênero

Num tal documento dos anos 90 parece como a oficial mais alta duma certa conservatória escreveu que ela é "O Conservador". (E parece que escreveu assim de forma consistente.) Isto soa-me estranho, porque pensei que ela seria "A Conservadora". Será que ela pode ser mesmo "O Conservador da Conservatória"? Ou é sempre "A Conservadora" quando é uma mulher?

Comment: Para os falantes de pt-BR: "[conservatória](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservat%C3%B3ria)" em Portugal é uma repartição pública com papel comparável ao do [cartório](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cart%C3%B3rio) no Brasil.

Comment: De notar ainda que "cartório" existe em Portugal também, mas com um significado mais restrito que no Brasil. Essa diferença é explicada no artigo da Wikipédia que @stafusa muito bem partilhou. :)

Comment: Uma mulher é _conservadora_, mas _conservador_ pode ser usado em sentido inclusivo (ou referindo-se em abstrato ao cargo). O uso do masculino pode mesmo ser obrigatório: _o empregado do mês é a Maria_, . _o maior político da década foi a Maria_. Se usasses o feminino poderia pensar-se que o universo de pessoas em consideração eram apenas mulheres.

Comment: Quando documentos são parecidos com formulários, a fim de preencher lacunas, seria comum encontrar o gênero no masculino. Já vi isto em receitas médicas e documentos de identificação.

Comment: @sumitani sim, entendo, mas no documento que eu vi, "O Conservador" foi escrito a mão, aparentemente pela mesma senhora.

Answer (score 1):

A palavra flexionada, "conservadora (de registros)", certamente existe, veja por exemplo essa [notícia](https://www.notarios.pt/OrdemNotarios/PT/Noticias/_Historico/_2009/CM+online+9+Janeiro+2009.htm), essas [notas de aula](https://www.studocu.com/pt/document/universidade-de-lisboa/direito/resumos/direitos-reais-principios-e-nocoes-basicas/2040329/view) e essa [capa](https://www.notarios.pt/NR/rdonlyres/CD4E5FA7-1DCB-4797-82D6-391D096AC07F/4675/AF_Capa_Edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o201_maio_junho.pdf) de revista:

[image]

Dito isso, uma busca por "conservadora de registros" revela um número bem modesto de resultados úteis, sugerindo que, por um tempo, o termo possa ter sido mantido no masculino, mesmo quando usado por mulheres.